# Order of variables of integration in double integral

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

This is a question from the actuarial practice set:

An insurance company insures a large number of drivers. Let X be the random variable
representing the company’s losses under collision insurance, and let Y represent the
company’s losses under liability insurance. X

$$f(x,y )=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{2x + 2 + y}{4}&(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,2]\\
      0\      &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Calculate the probability that the total company loss is at least 1.

The solution suggests to integrate with respect to y first:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^2 \frac{2x + 2 + y}{4} dy \, dx   $$

I thought this is more natural, yet it gives the wrong answer:

$$ \int_0^2 \int_{1-y}^1 \frac{2x + 2 + y}{4} dx \, dy  $$

Why does the latter not work?

Answer (score 1):

It is legal to interchange the order of integration, but be sure to express the limits properly. The region of integration is
$$ 0\le x\le 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 1-x\le y\le 2,$$
which is the intersection of the set $\{(x,y): x+y\ge 1\}$, corresponding to the event of interest, and the set $[0,1]\times[0,2]$, where the density is nonzero. So integrating first with respect to $y$ leads to the double integral as seen in the solution:
$$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=1-x}^2 f(x,y)dy\,dx.$$
If you integrate $y$ last, then you have to split the integral into two pieces, to handle the cases $0<y<1$ and $1<y<2$ separately, because the formula for the lower limit on $x$ changes at $y=1$:
$$\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=1-y}^1 f(x,y)dx\,dy +\int_{y=1}^2\int_{x=0}^1 f(x,y)dx\,dy.$$
Note that in both pieces the upper limit on $x$ remains fixed at $1$; it's the lower limit on $x$ that has to be defined piecewise.